# SSRS and MS Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-4

I had to do some changes in SSRS reports and deployed the same in the report server which is connected to CRM 4.0. I am unable to see the updated reports when I run the report in CRM 4.0. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: are you getting an error?  or is it just the same report as before it was updated?  this question is not clear enough to get any good responses.

Comment: Have you tried to update the report from within CRM or directly on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't update the report directly in Report Server. For CRM to pickup the changes, you must upload the report via CRM Customisations.

The reason for this is that CRM will modify the report to replace the connection strings and add hidden system-parameters to the report.